# Show that if $A \subset B \subset X$ then $f(A) \subset f(B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Show that if $A \subset B \subset X$ then $f(A) \subset f(B)$ where $f: X \to Y$ and $X,Y$ are sets. I am trying to do this using basic set theory definitions. I have that:

$ f(A) = \{ y \in Y : \exists a \in A : f(a) = y \}$ similarly $f(B) = \{ y \in Y : \exists b \in B : f(b) = y \}$.

My attempt:

Let $y \in f(A)$ then $\exists a \in A$ s.t. $f(a) = y$ but $a \in A \subset B$ so there exists a $a \in B$ s.t. $f(a) = y$. Since $y$ is arbitrary $f(A) \subset f(B)$. I feel as though this is wrong somehow - please help

Comment: Since $a\in A\subset B$ it follows that $a\in B$ and hence $f(a)\in f(B)$.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned I am trying ot do it using the definition of $f(A),f(B)$.

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying that when you say there exists an $a\in B$ you already know which $a$... the one you had previously.

Comment: Oh OK - so how would I formalise my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it almost right. Your wording is awkward. Perhaps you are thinking the right thing in your head but not expressing it correctly. In either case, let me clean it up.

$y \in f(A)$ means $y = f(a)$ for some $a \in A \subset B$. By definition of $A \subset B$, this implies $a \in B$. Therefore, $y = f(a)$ where we now consider $a \in B$. Note that this is the same $a$, not a different one, which your wording seems to imply. Therefore, $y \in f(B)$.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was thinking. Appreciate it!

Comment: Does the statement hold in the other direction?

Answer (score 0):

$$y\in f(A)\implies \exists x\in A: y=f(x).$$
Since $A\subset B$, then $x$ is also in $B$ and thus $y\in f(B)$.